# (list comprehension) getting more than one list with a for loop

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm using list comprehension with the for loop but what I'm looking for is: from a for loop get two lists .
Example (it's obviously not working but I want something  like that):

```
def f(i): return i*i
def g(i): return 1.0/(1+i*i)

seq1, seq2=[(f(i),g(i))
      for i in xrange(10)]
```

The result what I'm looking for has to be :

```
seq1= [f(0),f(1),..,f(9)]
seq2= [g(0),g(1),..,g(9)]
```

Is there a feasible solution?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: For things like this don't try to be clever, unless it's needed do two loops. It would be easier to read and maintain. List comprehensions should be simple one liners.

Comment: @Dan: Generally I agree, it's probably a case of premature optimization -- [the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization) -- but the `zip(*zip(...))` used in my answer is shown as an example in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=zip#zip), so I suspect it's a Python idiom the OP should learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do can be done, but it is not too much transparent...

In practice, you create a list of tuples and later you unpack the
tuples in two (three, etc) using `zip(*`

Using `zip` returns tuples, if you absolutely need lists you have to
jump through another hoop...

```
>>> def f(i): return i*i
>>> def g(i): return 1.0/(1+i*i)
>>> t1, t2 = zip(*[(f(i),g(i+1)) for i in range(5)])
>>> l1, l2 = map(list, zip(*[(f(i),g(i+1)) for i in range(5)]))
>>> print t1, t2
(0, 1, 4, 9, 16) (0.5, 0.2, 0.1, 0.058823529411764705, 0.038461538461538464)
>>> print l1, l2
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16] [0.5, 0.2, 0.1, 0.058823529411764705, 0.038461538461538464]
>>>
```

Comment: Why `for i, e in enumerate('asdef')` instead of just `for i in range(len('asdef'))` when `e` isn't being used?

Comment: No reason at all, I take your advice and edit my answer

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your update clarified (and simplified) things — and here's my updated answer written to work in both Python 2 & 3:

```
try:
    from itertools import izip
except ImportError:  # Python 3
    izip = zip
    xrange = range

def f(i): return i*i
def g(i): return 1.0/(1+i*i)

seq1, seq2 = map(list, izip(*[(f(i), g(i)) for i in xrange(10)]))

print('  i     ' + '  '.join(('{:5d}'.format(i) for i in xrange(10))))
print('seq1 = [' + ', '.join(('{:5d}'.format(v) for v in seq1)) + ']')
print('seq2 = [' + ', '.join(('{:.3f}'.format(v) for v in seq2)) + ']')
```

Output:

```
  i         0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9
seq1 = [    0,     1,     4,     9,    16,    25,    36,    49,    64,    81]
seq2 = [1.000, 0.500, 0.200, 0.100, 0.059, 0.038, 0.027, 0.020, 0.015, 0.012]
```

Comment: OK, I think I had to formulate my question better.
Let's suppose instead of c[i]+1 and b[i]+2 I have two functions taking i as parameter ex. f(i) and g(i) and they are independent from c and b. So to have something like that:
seq1, seq2=[(f(i),g(i))
      for i in xrange(c.shape[0])]

Comment: This answer suits you just the same -just replace the "i+ 1" and  "j +  2"  expressions for your function calls.

Comment: mimou: Not sure what you mean with the `xrange(c.shape[0])`. Please update your question with the additional information -- generally it's not a good idea to put a bunch of code in a comment.

Comment: martineau: Sorry for the confusion. I hope it's clearer after my last update!